# How to find out what is the license for a following Nuget package?

Tags: nuget

I've got this package. When one installs it there is no alert about license when I try to install it nor info about it anywhere. How do I know what is the license for the following Nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicQuery/ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a different package, for example https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/, you can see on the right hand side, it says "License: MIT". If you look at an older version, from before NuGet supported license expressions, there's a link for "license info". There's also a link to the "project site" and "source repository", from which you can try to find the license information.

The package you linked to doesn't have any of these, which means the author chose not to provide it. One option is to use the "contact owners" link on the nuget website and ask the package owner what the license is. Another option is to treat it as proprietary/unlicensed software and not use it.